# How to make a number like -1000 to be recognized on a s.isdigit() command?

Tags: python-3.x

My question is pretty straightforward:

How can I make python3 to recognize, for example, -1000 on a s.isdigit() or some command of a kind? My program must be able to separate -1000 as a number classification... I've been cracking my head to discover anyhow to do that... What command should I use for it to recognize the minus (-) symbol as part of the number?

```
line_number=int(input())
counter=0
counter_2=0
counter_hashtag=0
counter_3=0
counter_emoticons=0
list_strings=[]
i=0


while(counter<line_number):
    a=str(input())
    counter=counter+1
    list_strings.append(a)

for i in range(0,len(list_strings)):
    try:
        int(list_strings[i])
        is_int = True
        print("Hello")
    except ValueError:
        is_int = False
    if(list_strings[i].isalpha() or is_int):
        print(list_strings[i])
    else:
        if((list_strings[i])[0]=='#'):
            if((list_strings[i])[1:].isalpha()):
                counter_hashtag=counter_hashtag+1
             else:
                counter_emoticons=counter_emoticons+1
        else:
            if(not (list_strings[i])[0]=="-"):
                counter_emoticons=counter_emoticons+1
    counter_3=counter_3+1
    ############################################################################
    ############################################################################
    if(counter_hashtag>1):
        print(counter_hashtag, "hashtags were removed.")
    if(counter_hashtag==1):
        print("1 hashtag was removed.")
    if(counter_emoticons>1):
        print(counter_emoticons, "emoticons were removed.")
    if(counter_emoticons==1):
        print("1 emoticon was removed.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use a `try-except` block around an `int` constructor to test if a string contains a valid integer:

```
try:
    int(list_strings[i])
    is_int = True
except ValueError:
    is_int = False
```

Your `for` loop should therefore be revised as follows:

```
for i in range(0,len(list_strings)):
    try:
        int(list_strings[i])
        is_int = True
        print("Hello")
    except ValueError:
        is_int = False
    if(list_strings[i].isalpha() or is_int:
        print(list_strings[i])
    else:
        if((list_strings[i])[0]=='#'):
            if((list_strings[i])[1:].isalpha()):
                counter_hashtag=counter_hashtag+1
            else:
                counter_emoticons=counter_emoticons+1
        else:
            if(not (list_strings[i])[0]=="-"):
                counter_emoticons=counter_emoticons+1
    counter_3=counter_3+1
```

Comment: It didn't work... It stills recognizes -1000 as an emoticon :/

Comment: the program is not recognizing the try-except block I think

Comment: It definitely would work. Can you show me your updated code either by updating your question, or by editing my answer?

Comment: Saw your updated code. The `is_int` Boolean in my answer is meant to replace your `isdigit` test. You should not keep your original code with `isdigit`. Replace `(list_strings[i]).isdigit()` with `is_int`, and remove the unnecessary `if(is_int==True): print(is_int) if(is_int==False):` statements, and your code would work.

Comment: it still considers -xxxxx a emoticon

Comment: I just updated my answer with how you should apply the suggested check.

Comment: I didn't notice that you incorrectly used the `try` syntax. You should put `int(list_strings[i])` within the `try` block as I showed you, not as an argument to `try`. See my updated answer.

Comment: It has to be something else with your data then. Try the `try` block in Python shell and you'll see how it works. And then try printing out the content of `list_strings[i]` in each iteration to see if it is as you expected. It may contain certain extra characters that are not supposed to be part of an integer.

Comment: my .py archive was corrupted I guess, because I copied everything to another archive and it worked :)
Thank you very much